# Make single column editable in a UI5 smart table

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I want to create a smart table with an editable column. I am using the `metadata` annotations to generate the table. The table property (`editable = "true"`) makes all the columns editable. In my case, I want to make only a single column editable. I tried with the property `sap:updatable="true"` but it didn't work. Any ideas.
Thanks in advance.
This is my view by the way:

```
<mvc:View 
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    controllerName="QuickStartApplication3.controller.View1"
    xmlns:smartFilterBar="sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar"
    xmlns:smartTable="sap.ui.comp.smarttable">
    <smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar 
        id="smartFilterBar"
        entityType="Product">
        <smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
            <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration
                key="ProductId"
                visibleInAdvancedArea="true" 
                preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="true" >
            </smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
        </smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>

        <smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
            <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration
               key="Name"
               visibleInAdvancedArea="true" 
               preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="true" >
            </smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
        </smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>

        <smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
            <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration
                key="Category"
                visibleInAdvancedArea="true" 
                preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="true" >
            </smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
        </smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>

    </smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar>

    <smartTable:SmartTable 
        id="smartTable_ResponsiveTable"
        smartFilterId="smartFilterBar" 
        tableType="ResponsiveTable" 
        editable="false"
        entitySet="Products" 
        useVariantManagement="false"
        useTablePersonalisation="true" 
        header="Products" 
        showRowCount="true"
        useExportToExcel="true" 
        enableAutoBinding="true">
    </smartTable:SmartTable>
</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to put a simple comment to your question but could you provide a sample of your view so that I can understand more precisely what you do?

Have you tried the use the sap.m.Table object as detailed here in the documentation :
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TableEditable/preview

In order to have only certain cell editable you can manage it throught the template used  see below how I changed the template in the onInit method of the controller:

```
onInit : function(evt) {
                this.oModel = new JSONModel(jQuery.sap.getModulePath(
                        "sap.ui.demo.mock", "/products.json"));
                this.oTable = this.getView().byId("idProductsTable");
                this.getView().setModel(this.oModel);
                this.oReadOnlyTemplate = this.getView().byId(
                        "idProductsTable").removeItem(0);
                this.rebindTable(this.oReadOnlyTemplate, "Navigation");
                this.oEditableTemplate = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                    cells : [ new sap.m.ObjectIdentifier({
                        title : "{Name}",
                        text : "{ProductId}"
                    }), new sap.m.Input({
                        value : "{Quantity}",
                        description : "{UoM}"
                    }), new sap.m.Input({
                        value : "{WeightMeasure}",
                        description : "{WeightUnit}"
                    }), new sap.m.Input({
                        value : "{Price}",
                        description : "{CurrencyCode}"
                    }) ]
                });
```

If you don't use this object, then please tell me which one, I might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks @Almiriad for your response, but, I think this won't work with smart table. I edited my post and added my View code if this could help.

Comment: Hi, I see that you use a responsive table type, I think something can be done this way, see the following example, the same table type is used and the entire template of the table is provided. https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smarttable.smarttablesmartmicrochart/code Have you tried to do the same and see the behavior? Which fields are editable, which aren't ?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [“Preview”-screenshot and the metadata.xml](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/f712d30f9e2d4abd9670263f89542f2b.html).

What happens if you set editable = "true" and annotate all properties of ‘Products’ with sap:updatable=”false”,
except for the single property that shall be editable, which you set to sap:updatable=”true”.

Don’t annotate entity set ‘Products’ with sap:updatable (or make sure that sap:updatable=”true”).